# Can I read my app extension's info.plist in my host app?

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I've built a today widget and I want to show what version is running in my host app's about screen. Is there a way to do that?

I've tried replacing `[NSBundle mainBundle]` with `bundleWithIdentifier` but that fails. So, is there a way to get the `infoDictionary` from he extension bundle, or am I wasting my time?

Comment: You can always use NSUserDefaults by suite name, `[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.mycompany.myapp"]` set the version in the main app and access it in the extension.

Comment: That works if the extension was opened before the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pull this off by specifying the direct path to the extension's bundle. It looks like app extensions live in the `PlugIns/` folder in your app's main bundle. You can create an instance of `NSBundle` by using `-initWithPath:`. For example:

```c
- (NSBundle *)appExtensionBundle {
    NSString *plugInsPath = [NSBundle mainBundle].builtInPlugInsPath;
    NSString *appExtensionPath = [plugInsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyTodayExtension.appex"];
    return [[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath:appExtensionPath];
}
```

NOTE: This code was tested only with a Today extension. You should test to make sure it works correctly if you have other types of extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Application and Extension cant access each others code and address space. They can only share data using Sharing the container using AppGroup or by using Shared NSUserDefault.

Using both the approach will require to run your extension atleast once.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this is case.